# MessageDispatcher is NULL when it is migrated from web logic server to tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am migrating my spring soap based application from web logic 10.3.5 server to tomcat 7 server. When used the existing war file from weblogic in to tomcat, i got more no of exceptions. I think tomcat is not loading the files. I got around 1440 aspectJ core files in tomcat. some of the exceptions are like

```
class org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher
class org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory$Jaxp13XPathExpression
class org.springframework.xml.namespace.SimpleNamespaceContext to -- (NullPointerException) null
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I just conveyed it short. if it is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my issue. When i checked my javac and java version's both are miss matching. javac -version is 1.6 and java -version is 1.8. Also my application is built on java 1.6 where as tomcat(7.0.42) java jvm version displayed as 1.8. I have changed tomcat java jvm version to 1.6. now all my exceptions related to application run are gone.

i have look into project specific errors to resolve.

Thank you for your time.